# Problem where you are supposed to use Kirchhoffs laws

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

Apologies for the non-descriptive title, didn't really know how to word it.

I'm familiar with Kirchhoffs Laws, studied them in high school physics like many others. Got pretty good at problems requiring them (was one of the nerdy kids). My cousin, who's studying to be an electrician, asked me if I could help him with a problem. After seeing it, I was left scratching my head because the circuit made no sense to me. Here is a replica of it I drew in CircuitLab:

[image]

You are supposed to find the the values of the currents I1, I2 and I3 by using Kirchhoffs laws. I drew the red arrows because the original circuit had similar ones, I naturally assumed they were describing the flow of the respective currents. But how can there even be any flow? All the positive terminal are connected to each other, same with the negatives. And after adding a ground under V4 in CircuitLab, all the ammeters had negative values. So the arrows are all wrong? Am I overthinking it? Is it just a trick question? Or do I not understand the laws as well as I thought?

Comment: You haven't responded to anyone, yet. Maybe busy? Anyway, you say you are reasonably familiar with Kirchhoff's Laws (I take this to mean both KCL and KVL.) Which of the two did you apply here? And can you show any work? (It would help to see how you approach things, in formulating a more helpful answer for you.)

Comment: I asked the question late at night. Woke up a couple of hours ago and have been doing household stuff. I'm a new student at a college, so yes I'm rather busy. I haven't tried much because I was stumped. One trick I remembered from high school was going around a particular part of the circuit and summing up the voltages, equaling it to zero. I did it with the right side of the circuit (V4 to R1 to V3 to R3) and then the left side. From the arrows I surmised that I3 = I1+I2. I got a system of equations, but the wrong answer. I'm more interested in the flow. See my comment to James' answer.

Comment: if someone else doesn't get you what you want sooner, I'll write something up in some hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've waited long enough. Here are my thoughts for now...

### KVL Analysis

Below, I'll expound a little on some of your comments. But let's get right to it, at first.

Your schematic is on the left, below. But on the right, I swapped \$R_3\$ and \$V_3\$. They are in series and it makes no difference (for analysis anyway) if I do that.

Or I could have left those two alone and instead swapped the others on the left and right sides of the schematic to put the voltage sources on top and the resistors at the bottom. It's all the same for analysis.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffi6Ro.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've also added a ground reference to the right side. You get to pick any one node for that. By selecting one node to be shared for communication purposes as "zero" (the ground symbol), then I can talk about a node voltage and the listener will now that the quoted value is ***in reference*** to the ground node. Voltages are still always *voltage differences* between two nodes. But by creating an implied reference for communication, so we can simplify our language, a little.

Your case has two loops; the left side loop and the right side loop. Since you already have nice arrows suggesting a counter-clockwise direction for each loop, let's go with it. I'll be using the left side schematic from above, just as you originally wrote it (I won't use the right side... at least for now.)

$$\begin{align*}
0\:\text{V} -\left(I_1-I_3\right)R_3 + V_3 -I_1\,R_2-V_2&=0\:\text{V}
\\\\
0\:\text{V}+V_4-I_3\,R_1-V_3-\left(I_3-I_1\right)R_3&=0\:\text{V}
\end{align*}$$

Note that \$I_2=I_3-I_1\$. Take a look at the loops and the current directions for those two loops to see why this is.

The above solves out such that \$I_1=\frac4{15}\:\text{A}\$ and \$I_3=\frac45\:\text{A}\$. So, \$I_2=I_3-I_1=\frac8{15}\:\text{A}\$. And that's it.

### Further Redrawing

We could go further than we did, above. Now that the voltage sources are all referenced against ground, we can remove the shared wire between the ground connections (removing the wire doesn't change the fact that they are all still connected to ground) and then also remove the voltage sources, themselves, and simply label those ends of the resistors, accordingly:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBlhLj.png)</sup>

On the right side, the voltage sources are now gone (as 2-terminal devices, anyway.) But I've retained the current loop currents (and \$I_2\$) and am now arranging things to show those currents all going from top to bottom (in the same direction.) As a result, we have an unknown node voltage that I called \$V_{_\text{X}}\$.

(Hmm. Where did the ground go?)

That can be solved as:

$$V_{_\text{X}}=\frac{V_3\,R_1\,R_2+V_2\,R_1\,R_3+V_4\,R_2\,R_3}{R_1\,R_2+R_1\,R_3+R_2\,R_3}=8\,\frac45\:\text{V}$$

Now we can find the currents as \$I_1=\frac{V_{_\text{X}}-V_2}{R_2}=\frac4{15}\:\text{A}\$, \$I_2=\frac{V_{_\text{X}}-V_3}{R_3}=\frac8{15}\:\text{A}\$, and \$I_3=\frac{V_4-V_{_\text{X}}}{R_1}=\frac4{5}\:\text{A}\$.

Note that the answers are still the same.

This emphasizes that you need to become comfortable with different ways of simplifying circuits, while retaining the questions you are interested in answering. And you often can do a lot of simplification.

### Expatiation

(There's no English word that carries the positive connotations of the Czech verb, "vykládat." The closest, but not really close, is perhaps expound or expatiate. So that's what I'm using.)

> I'm a new student at a college, so yes I'm rather busy.

Got it. Some students are so busy they almost cannot remember much from a morning class as they head into an afternoon one. It can become a bit of a blur.

> One trick I remembered from high school was going around a particular
> part of the circuit and summing up the voltages, equaling it to zero.

That's the KVL part of Kirchhoff's laws. That would not be the KCL part. So now I know what you were trying to use. Which helps a lot.

> I did it with the right side of the circuit (V4 to R1 to V3 to R3) and
> then the left side. From the arrows I surmised that I3 = I1+I2. I got
> a system of equations, but the wrong answer. I'm more interested in
> the flow.

Okay. See the above work.

> I'm asking out of my own curiosity. How can there be any flow of
> electrons in this circuit when there's no path an electron can take to
> reach a lower potential.

Just to be clear (may as well be), a "voltage" always has two points -- the question is always, "What's the voltage *difference* between this point here and that point there?" You cannot have a voltage value at a solo point. Doesn't make any sense to even ask. It's always between two points.

You correctly write (I like to think so, anyway) when you say *"... no path an electron can take to reach a lower potential."* That's a sufficient way (for many purposes) to keep things in mind.

Note that in the last schematic on the right side, above... the one where there are no voltage sources directly showing and only three resistors there... that I am showing that there are paths from higher potential to lower potentials. So there will be currents.

Charges have a force acting on them when there is a voltage difference between two points. And they will move under that force if there is a path by which those charges *can* move.

Normally, these forces would cause acceleration. And in a vacuum where there isn't anything to get in the way of their motion, they do accelerate until impact. But when passing through matter, like copper, they keep running into things along the way and being forced (essentially) to come to a stop before starting up again. So they wind up having a bunch of short paths of increasing acceleration, followed by an abrupt crash into something, then starting back up again, etc. This results in an average velocity rather than an increasing acceleration. But remember that in a vacuum that's no longer the case and they will just accelerate under the force until they run into something along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Voltage sources are not diodes. A 4V voltage source has 4V at all times... even if something else tries to make it a higher voltage! If V3, for example, didn't allow any current flow, then its voltage would be too high. That means there is current flow.

Don't try this in real life because it can break the power supply - most aren't designed for it.

If an ammeter reads a negative value, that means it's backwards - which is okay and does not break it. I'm not sure which way around the ammeters in CircuitLab are. Perhaps the way you drew them is opposite from the arrows.

Sometimes, textbooks do draw the arrows opposite to the current direction, on purpose, to confuse you, and the correct answer is negative. Other times, the arrows are drawn in the correct direction and it's positive. On this circuit, I'd hazard a guess that all three arrows are correct, so if you're getting negative measurements on CircuitLab, it means the ammeters are backwards compared to the arrows.

Comment: "on purpose, to confuse you" -- or on purpose, because in industry negative currents are often expressed and have meaning.  For instance, the current-handling capabilities of an IC pin may be expressed as +10mA (when it's driving current out) and -1.5mA (when it's sinking current).

Comment: @TimWescott Isn't it the opposite way around, negative sign when sourcing current and positive sign when sinking current? For both inputs and outputs.

Comment: Uh -- maybe?  I generally remember that stuff _really well_ when I'm actually looking at datasheets.

Comment: Now that you mention it, the ammeters in CircuitLab are backwards actually. Intuitively one thinks that they share the same orientation as letter "A" on them, but that's a mistake. Haven't used the program in a while so I had forgotten. In any case, I already knew the thing about voltage sources not being diodes. But I don't understand how that's relevant to the current flow. So as to not repeat myself, see my comment to James' answer. Specifically the example I give with the batteries. Even if the batteries had different voltages, there would still not be any flow.

Answer (score 1):

I hope your cousin really exists!

Swap the positions of V3 and R3 which won't affect the currents and then use Millman's theorem to find the voltage at the top of the circuit. Then you can use Ohms law across each resistor to find the three currents.

The current directions as depicted by the arrows are correct.

[image: Solution]

Comment: He does. But I'm asking out of my own curiosity. I should have been more clear with the question. I don't understand how there can be a current. If I connect 2 batteries together, + to + and - to -, nothing happens. And if I connect a light source between them, it won't light up. Isn't that essentially what this circuit is doing? The way I've understood it, for there to be a current in a particular circuit, electrons have to go from one place to another. How can there be any flow of electrons in this circuit when there's no path an electron can take to reach a lower potential.

Comment: I didn't know about Millman's theorem so I've been reading about it a bit on wikipedia. I didn't really understand the "proof" behind the theorem because how can you calculate the current in the branch by inputting the voltage of the source within that branch into Ohm's law? You need to use the voltage across the resistor in order to get the current, but we don't know what that is so how does that work? Then I remembered something I always forget... These are not batteries, but theoretical voltage sources with no internal resistance....

Comment: However, I'm getting the wrong currents. I2 for example, is supposed to be 0.5333A. Your method gives 0.9777A.

Comment: @ShootinLemons Once you have determined the voltage at the top of the circuit (let's call it V) using Millman's Theorem you can then use Ohms law across each resistor to find the currents. For example, for the middle  branch, I2 = (V-4)/9. To give you a hand, using Millman's Theorem, the voltage at the top of the circuit, V comes out as 8.8 V. Prove this for yourself. Therefore I2 = (8.8-4)/9 = 0.53333 A